# AngularJS: Failed to instantiate module error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, controller, dependencies

i know this question has already been asked, but i could not find the answer to my personal case. I'm sure it's a stupid thing i didn't notice but i'm not getting out of it.

I'll post all the code i have (it's not that much) because i can not find the real origin of the error.

This is my app.js file:

```
'use strict'; 

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'appControllers'
]);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/faq', {
    templateUrl: 'faq/faq.html',
    controller: 'FaqCtrl'
  }).
  when('/log', {
    templateUrl: 'log/log.html',
    controller: 'LogCtrl'
  }).
  [...]
  when('/settings', {
    templateUrl: 'settings/settings.html',
    controller: 'SettingsCtrl'
  }).
  otherwise({redirectTo: '/homepage'});
}]);
```

While here is where i hold my controllers, controllers.js:

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

var appControllers = angular.module('appControllers', []);

appControllers.controller('FaqCtrl', [function() {

}]);

appControllers.controller('HomepageCtrl', [function() {

}]);

[...]

appControllers.controller('SettingsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
/*
  $scope.myData = {};
  $scope.myData = function(item, event) {

    var response = $http.get("myURL");

    response.success(function() {

      alert("ok");
    });

    response.error(function() {

      alert("error");
    }); 
*/
});
```

And here is settings.html:

```
<div ng-controller="SettingsController" >
    <button ng-click="myData.doClick(item, $event)">Send AJAX Request</button>
    <br/>
    Data from server: {{myData.fromServer}}
  </div>
```

Now, if i run it with the code inside SettingsCtrl commented it works fine, but if i decomment it, the page does not end its loading (even if i don't go to the Settings section) and the error is this:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module appControllers due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'appControllers' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

What did i miss?

I'm sure it will be a stupid thing, but i'm a newbie with AngularJS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mistype your code here, or is the function(item, event) missing "};" at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you uncomment the curly braces are not closed properly.

```
appControllers.controller('SettingsController', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.myData = {};
  $scope.myData = function(item, event) {

    var response = $http.get("myURL");

    response.success(function() {

      alert("ok");
    });

    response.error(function() {

      alert("error");
    }); 
  }
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/4sltz2Bwai9zm9FLkyC7?p=preview

One more issue, the controller name is not matching but you probably have figured it out already.

Comment: Thank you, like every time i was wondering what i didn't understand, and it was just a parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't include the controller file in your `index.html`

Answer (score 0):

you lost a "}"

```
appControllers.controller('SettingsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.myData = {};
  $scope.myData = function(item, event) {
    var response = $http.get("myURL");
    response.success(function() {
      alert("ok");
    });
    response.error(function() {
      alert("error");
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. It always ends like this.